# Heroku 500 internal server error, TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mailgun, cloud9

first time posting.
Im trying to make mailgun send me an email for new subscribers
but when i filled the form it gives me 500 internal server error and TypeError.

## Error log

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
>   TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
>   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:9:in `[]'
>   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:9:in`create'

Is there something wrong with my ContactsController?

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
 def new
@contact = Contact.new
end

def create
 @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
 if @contact.save
  name = params[:contact][:name]
  email = params[:contact][:email]
  body = params[:contact][:comments]
  ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver
   flash[:success] = "Message sent."
   redirect_to new_contact_path
 else
   flash[:danger] = @contact.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
   redirect_to new_contact_path
 end
end  

 private
    def contact_params
     params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end  
end
```

## contact_email.html.erb

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
       <p>You have received a message from the site's contact form, from
       <%= "#{ @name }, #{ @email }." %></p>
       <p><%= @body %></p>
     </body>

   </html>
```

The weird thing is that if i run my codes in development via cloud9 server it runs fine but in production via heroku server it gives me an error after trying to submit the contact us form fully filled out.
Also im learning how to code by following this [website](http://upskillcourses.com/courses/enrolled/119763).
The issue is with lesson 78.

Comment: Inspect `params`. It looks like `params[:contact]` returns `Array` instead of 'Hash'

Comment: `params[:contact]` is a String or an Array, it's not a hash.

So when you do `params[:contact][:name]` it wasn't expecting `:name` it was expecting an integer.

Comment: Could you please post your view and that will help identify what the problem might be in building your `params`

Answer (score -1):

name, email, body - have to be string.

```
inspect it by 
name.class
email.class
body.class
```

ActionMailer can work only with basic types(like string), but in you code someone in **name, email, body** is a symbol class.